# stm32 HardFault_Handler after reset

Tags: c, stm32, cubemx

I am currently developing a stm32f103C8 based pcb. The current project state can be viewed in this [GitHub Project](https://github.com/teeheee/puzzle-box).

The problem that I am facing, is that I can not run the code without debugging the device.
My Question is: what can I do to make the code run without the debugger?

## Setup

### PCB

I use the following [Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRjxW.png). Currently the battery managment and the external clock is not populated. So I use the interal oscillator. I power the device through 5V source which is regulated by the voltage regulator.

### Programming

I use a st-link v2 with SWD. Only swclk, swdio and gnd are connected.
For developing the application code I use cubemx (ide and code generator).

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; Copyright (c) 2019 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.</center></h2>
  *
  * This software component is licensed by ST under BSD 3-Clause license,
  * the "License"; You may not use this file except in compliance with the
  * License. You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *                        opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
static int open_event = 0;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

void open(void)
{
    //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(100);
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_Delay(2);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_Delay(19);
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}


void close(void)
{
    //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(100);
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_Delay(1);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_Delay(18);
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */
  

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  HAL_Delay(500);
  close();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  int last_open_event = 1;
  HAL_Delay(100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //enable esp8266
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET); //enable esp8266
  HAL_Delay(20);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET); //enable esp8266

 // HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET); //enable esp8266
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  int byte_index = 0;
  char* code_word = "open";
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    char byte;
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, &byte, 1);
    if(code_word[byte_index] == byte)
        byte_index++;
    else if(code_word[0] == byte)
        byte_index=1;
    else
        byte_index=0;
    if(byte_index == 2)
    {
        open();
        byte_index = 0;
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA6 PA8 PA15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB11 PB12 PB15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */

  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

## What I have tested

- when diconnecting Boot0 and Boot1 from GND I can run the code with the debugger normally
- when connecting Boot0 and Boot1 to GND the debugger directly jumps to the HardFault_Handler
- the code never runs when connected to Boot0 and Boot1 without debugger.
- Voltage level is stable
- There is no difference in the behavior when resetting the MCU with power cycling and NRST.

Answer (score 4):

It is enough boot0 toi be connected to GND. Boot1 means something only if the boot0 is high.

Instant hard fault after the reset usually indicates that the initial stack address is invalid (offset 0 in the Vector Table)

Check the linker script if you have the correct one.

If you use atollic studio or STM32CUBE IDE you can use hard fault plugin - which makes all the hard job for you (taking stuff from the stack and reading the appropriate system registers)

Comment: thank you, your answer led me to a [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/432275/stm32f4-hardfault-handler) about hard fault error. There the hard fault was generated by using a wrong device. I then rechecked the stm32 mcu written on my controller and it was stm32f103c4 and not stm32f103c8. Changing the device name solved the problem.

Comment: @AlexTeeheee, then write a separate answer to your question, or delete it. Do not leave it current state.

Comment: @AlexTeeheee wrong device usually == wrong linker script. For example if toyr device has less memory that in the linker script and most of them place stack at the bottom of the memory, you will get the HF instantly